# How to draw candlestick bar inside a column cell of PyQt4 QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreewidget, candlestick-chart

I am trying to make a simple application with pyqt.
What I want to make is a tree view with candlestick bar like the below,

[image]

I decided to make it using [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980149/multiple-columns-in-pyqt4-potentially-using-qtreewidget).

But still, I couldn't find how to draw candlestick bar inside a cell of widget row.

Can you suggest any sample code or guideline for getting cell coordinates and drawing a bar inside column cells ?

Comment: How are you generating the candlestick bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you're planning to generate the candlestick bar.

If you're able to generate an image using some other library, you can create a `QPixmap` from the image and put it inside a `QLabel`, then insert the `QLabel` in to a specific cell using [`QTreeWidget.setItemWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget).

If you plan on drawing the candlestick bar yourself, you could use a `QItemDelegate` and override the `paint` method to draw the graph yourself based on data you set on each `QTreeWidgetItem`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'll search for some examples about QItemDelegate.